# Get ndk-gdb to work: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-gdb

There are several questions about this, and I've tried a couple of the solutions, but I'm still getting the above error.

My Project root is

```
/Users/me/main/src/task/task2/apps/MyApp
```

My jni folder is

```
/Users/me/main/src/task/task2/modules/jni
```

Android.mk is here

```
/Users/me/main/src/task/task2/modules/jni/Android.mk
```

Application.mk is here

```
/Users/me/main/src/task/task2/modules/jni/Application.mk
```

Here's where my ndk log ends:

```
Android NDK: Found project path: /Users/me/main/src/task/task2/modules
Android NDK: Ouput path for intermediate files: /Users/me/main/src/task/task2/modules/obj
Android NDK: Ouput path for generated library files: /Users/me/main/src/task/task2/modules/libs
Android NDK: Parsing /Users/me/main/src/task/task2/modules/jni/Application.mk
Android NDK:   APP_PIE is 
Android NDK:   Enabling -fPIE
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: Android.mk    
/Users/me/android/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/add-application.mk:199: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

I haven't defined APP_BUILD_SCRIPT in my Application.mk, but I have defined NDK_PROJECT_ROOT environment variable in my .bash_profile to point to the modules directory (i.e: parent of jni directory).

Any ideas?